# Using session state in http handler

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, ihttphandler

I have an HTTP Handler that requires access to session state. After reading some other questions on SO, I discovered that I needed to add `IReadOnlySessionState` to my handler in order to get session state.  I did that, and now I can see in my `IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest()` that `context.Session` has a value.

This is good, but the problem is now `context.Request.HttpMethod` is always a `GET`.  If I remove IReadOnlySessionState, `context.Request.HttpMethod` is `POST` which is what I expect.  So somehow adding `IReadOnlySessionState` has caused it to change my `HttpMethod` to `GET`, and I don't know why.

My code looks something like this:

```
public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{
    bool IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    void IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (context.Request.HttpMethod)
            {
                case "GET":
                    HandleGet(context);
                    break;
                case "POST":
                    HandlePost(context);
                    break;
                case "PUT":
                    HandlePut(context);
                    break;
                case "DELETE":
                    HandleDelete(context);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Do something useful here
        }
    }
}
```

I'm invoking the handler using WinHttp in C++:

```
HINTERNET hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnection, _T("POST"), webServicePath, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, WINHTTP_FLAG_REFRESH);

BOOL rc = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), -1, (LPVOID)content, reqLen, reqLen, NULL);
```

Passing "POST" to `WinHttpOpenRequest()` as the method, then sending the request with `WinHttpSendRequest()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, but I'd still like an explanation if anyone can help - I had `<sessionState cookieless="true"/>` in my `web.config`.  When I changed that to `false`, my request came through as a POST.  Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 2):

`IRequireSessionState` will work with POST requests, like this:

```
public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequireSessionState
```

Read [IRequiresSessionState Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx) for documentation.

Comment: I tried using IRequiresSessionState instead of IReadOnlySessionState, but the result is the same...

Comment: +1 for your help.  I got it fixed, but I don't know why that worked.  See my answer if you can explain it...